# Azure Synapse analytics connectivity with Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, connectivity, azure-synapse

I have created server less synapse analytics with database and table in it.

I have tried using the SQL query to view data within synapse analytics and can view it as expected but when I try to connect Tableau desktop version 2020.2.9 (as the connector is only available in version 2020.2 and above) with connector provide in tableau the connection establish successfully as I can see the list of database and tables in it but when I try to click on the table to view data below issue pop-up.

```
An error occurred while communicating with Azure Synapse Analytics
Unable to connect to the server. Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.
Error Code: 2F0F5E42
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]External table 'dbo' is not accessible because location does not exist or it is used by another process.
The table "[dbo].[Diagnosis]" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check what type of server less synapse you are using whether a standard dedicated cluster or an On-Demand cluster. Further, you can reach to Tableau support team to check with the connectivity based on your cluster type.

Comment: Hi @Roshan : If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !